# ASP.NET MVC CDN bundling error happen even is enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to register cdn bundle and I got error like:

> System.ArgumentException   HResult=0x80070057   Message=The URL
> 'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js' is not valid.
> Only application relative URLs (~/url) are allowed. Parameter name:
> virtualPath   Source=System.Web.Optimization   StackTrace:    at
> System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.Include(String virtualPath,
> IItemTransform[] transforms)    at
> CegekaDsa.DynamicsEmpire.Portals.CustomerApp.Startup.RegisterBundles()
> in C:\Users\myuser\source\reposmyapp\App_Start\Startup.cs:line 15
> at
> CegekaDsa.DynamicsEmpire.Portals.CustomerApp.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder
> app) in C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\myapp\Startup.cs:line 15

I use code:

```
public void RegisterBundles()
{
      var bundles = BundleTable.Bundles;
      bundles.UseCdn = true;
      var nprogressCdn = new[] { "https://unpkg.com/nprogress@0.2.0/nprogress.js", "https://unpkg.com/nprogress@0.2.0/nprogress.css" };
      var jqueryCdn = new[] { "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js", "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" };

      bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", jqueryCdn[0])
        .Include(jqueryCdn[1]));

      BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Comment: Are you running a DEBUG build?

Comment: Yes. I am in DEBUG mode

Comment: @Filburt removed pictures and add text instead

Comment: `.Include(jqueryCdn[1])` must use a local version to be used as an alternative to the CDN.